# Excluir a imagem clicada do local storage

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, localstorage

Basicamente fiz um sistema de favoritar imagens ao clicar para salvar no local storage.

```js
let favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || []

localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites))
```

Eu consegui listar todas as imagens favoritadas em uma pagina, percorrendo-as e adicionando uma função de onclick para cada, e queria remover apenas a imagem que eu clicar.

segue código completo: https://codepen.io/bielb2/pen/dyMWmMa

Comment: a resposta que eu dei te ajudou?

Comment: vou verificar agora

Comment: lembra que voce tem que adicionar o onclick="removeimg(this)" nas miniaturas de imagem que aparece na div para escolher qual quer remover

Comment: fiz de tudo, mas não estou conseguindo adicionar o onclick nas imagens, tentei fazer pelo innerHTML mas não reconhece a função...

Comment: cara consegui arrumar, deu certo a parte de excluir cada imagem, só não estou conseguindo listar todas agora.

Comment: como assim nao esta listando ?

Comment: valeu mesmo pela ajuda, você me deu uma base de como remover as imagens, só que acontece outro problema. O modo como criei o localStorage é diferente das atribuições que você fez abaixo, o que acontece quando executa a função é um conflito, e fica dando error na página devida a outras definições de JSON que eu fiz. Acredito que eu tenha que arrumar o código para evitar esses conflitos

Comment: olha o vídeo para você ver o que acontece: https://ik.imagekit.io/b0g9wlasxh/Peek_27-08-2020_18-21_ECxuTASRg.mp4

Comment: pelo oq eu vi o erro e no momento que vc da favorites.push na function updateFavorites() oq exatamente vc faz nela?

Comment: acabei de adicionar uma atualização na resposta modificando sua função updateFavorites() da uma olhada e ve se vai

Comment: editei tambem a função de removeimg , percei um erro e corrigi, tente novamente

Comment: nice, deu certo!!! Porém só consigo adicionar 2 imagens no localStorage, não deixa eu adicionar mais.

Comment: modifiquei e corrigir o bug, coloca o remove e o updateFavorites e testa, caso funcione marque q a resposta funcionou

Comment: tudo certo, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: eu adicionei uma function q atualiza a div quando vc clica na imagem que quer remover, eu ia usar o empty porem n tava indo por essa ração fiz desse modo

Comment: testei aqui, ficou muito bom! Eu estava dando reload na pagina toda vez que excluía alguma imagem, esse código para atualizar a div me ajudou muito. O problema é que ele some com meu conteúdo do modal (o X para fechar por exemplo some)

Comment: atualizei função que atualiza a div e corrigir o bug que apagava a fraze da div acho que ficou melhor da uma olhada

Comment: ficou ótimo, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo oque vc falou uma das solução seria essa adicione `onclick="removeimg(this)"` nas img quando for mostrar e crie essa nova função

```
        function removeimg(el){
   //prgar src clicado
    var src = el.src;
  //prgar item do storege
    storege =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
    let newimg= false;
   //foreache nos item
    storege.forEach(img=>{
        if(src != img){
            if(!newimg){
                newimg = [img];
                console.log(newimg);
            }else{
               newimg.push(img);
            }
        }
        });
       //salvar as imagem que ele não clicou no favorito
        localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(newimg))
atualizardiv();    
}
```

mudando a função updateFavoritos

```
     function updateFavorites() {
    const { existsInLocalStorage, index, imageSource } = getState()

   // existsInLocalStorage
     //   ? favorites.splice(index, 1)
       // : favorites.push(imageSource)
    let quantidade = favorites.length;
    if(quantidade>0){
        favorites.push(imageSource)
                localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites))
        }else{
         favorites=[imageSource];
         localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites))
        }
    }
```

//atualizar a div quando remover a imagem

```
    function atualizardiv(){
        $('.modal').innerHTML='';
        $('.modal').innerHTML=' <h3>Clique <span id="remove">aqui</span> para remover todas as imagens</h3>'+
           ' <span class="X" draggable="true">&times;</span>';
    storege =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
    storege.forEach(img=>{
     $('.modal').innerHTML= $('.modal').innerHTML+'<img src="'+img+'" onclick="removeimg(this)"/>';
     });
}
```